# Load table from Ajax JSON with angular and ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I try to load a table in HTML from Ajax json, using Angular and ng-repeat.
My problem is that the JSON is a bit complicated and I don't know how to access "informationstyp", which is what I want to display in the table.
The root of the JSON ("values") is a list. Next level ("informationstyper") is also a list.

How can I get "informationstyp" into the table?
What should I write instead of **{{data.arendeslagId}}** in my html?

What I want in my table is:

FK1002

FK1003

FK1004

Thank you for your help.

My html:

```
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Arendeslagid</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="data in infotyper">
                <td>{{data.arendeslagId}}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

My JavaScript:

```
    $scope.infotyper = "";

    $scope.invoke = function() {
        $.ajax({
               "cache": false,
               "async": true,
               "crossDomain": true,
               "url": url",
               "method": "POST",
               "headers": {
                   "cache-control": "no-cache",
               },
            success: function (response) {
                   $scope.infotyper= response;
               }
           });
        };
```

My JSON-response:

[image]

Comment: you can use $http service methods in angular instead of jquery ajax.

Comment: @hasan Thank you, I have now changed it to $http

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change this:

```
success: function (response) {
  $scope.infotyper= response;
}
```

To this:

```
success: function (response) {
  $scope.infotyper= response.values;
  $scope.$apply();
}
```

If you are using AngularJS I strongly suggest you to use `$http` service instead of jQuery for AJAX requests

Comment: That's not working either. How can I get into the next level in JSON ("informationstyper")?

Comment: That field is an Array. So you need another ng-repeat for cycling inside those elements. For example: `<tr ng-repeat="data in infotyper">
<td>{{data.arendeslagId}}</td>
<td ng-repeat="typer in data.informationstyper">{{typer.informationstyp}}</td>
            </tr>`

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed!